# Display XY coordinates (with different lengths) in ArcGIS does not work

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, excel, xy

I have a list of Excel lat long coordinates in a spreadsheet that I want to import as points in ArcMap by displaying the XY Data.

```
lat      lon
5235746   486124
5236799   487447
5238042   489453
523686    486487
5236528   49301
```

However, ArcMap does not seem to recognise/display my coordinate data as points. I think because there are some 6-numbered coordinates in there as well. How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: You have tried Make XY Event layer? Or how do you import the data?

Comment: No I have added the spreadsheet to ArcMap and then tried to "Display XY data"

Comment: The tricky part is that I have coordinate numbers of varying lengths, some are displayed with 6 numbers, some with 7.

Comment: You will have to specify which coordinate system your points are in. Those aren't latitudes and longitudes, it looks more like UTM to me. Do you know the coordinate reference system of your points? Or, do you know approximately where your points are supposed to be in the world?

Comment: As you said, some of your coordinate values seem inconsistent, some have less digits, it looks like some may have been mistyped. This will be harder to deal with... maybe you can try adding a "0" (multiply them by 10) and see if it makes sense.

Comment: If those numbers are representative, as FSimardGIS said, they look like UTM, with lat = Y / northing values and lon = X / easting values. The 5- and 4- digit values are probably corrupt. You need to know the UTM zone number. What location does the data represent (longitude value, city, county, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel reload your file and export it in CSV format. Reload the CSV file in ArcMap. CSV files do wonders.
Also always remember that we are used to say Lat-Long, however from a mathematical point of view, I always say Long-Lat to remind myself that "Long is X" and "Lat is Y".

Comment: Strange, when I save the spreadsheet in CSV format, the 'latitude' column disappears..

Comment: That is an Excel thing, try selecting the data and then save as csv (I mean in Excel)

Comment: Actually, it seems to be an ArcGIS thing. I can see the lat lon fields in the attribute table. But the Display XY tool does not recognise the lat field. The Make XY Event Layer does recognise both tho, however it gives me an error. I really think that the varying lengths of the coordinates might be the problem here, don't you think?

Comment: I can't remember when was the time I used space delimited files, I have always used Comma Separated Values (CSV) it resolves all unnecessary issues in my point of view.